Handling large geospatial datasets for dynamic WebGIS application with PostGIS, Mapbox
I'm developing a WebGIS application that displays snow depth data for ski slopes using PostGIS, Mapbox, and Martin. My workflow is as follows:

Process LiDAR data to produce GeoTIFFs of snow depth.
Convert GeoTIFFs to vector GeoJSON.
Load GeoJSON data into PostGIS using ogr2ogr.
Serve vector tiles using Martin.
Display the data on a Mapbox map.

The problem is that my dataset is very detailed, with around 3,000,000 records for each snow depth layer, but the geographic extent is quite small (ski slopes). Performance is a major issue, with it taking around 26 seconds to display the data in the browser.
Here are the approaches I've tried and the issues encountered:

GeoServer with PostGIS and WFS: Very slow due to the large dataset size.
Directly loading GeoJSON in the browser using Mapbox or Deck.gl: Poor performance due to the size of the dataset.
Using Martin to serve MVT tiles from PostGIS: Still very slow (26s to load at a 12 zoom level).
Node.js backend generating MVT using ST_AsMVT from PostGIS: Same performance issues (30s to load at a 12 zoom level).

The application is dynamic, meaning more snow depth data will be uploaded regularly, so I need to handle an increasing amount of data efficiently.
How can I optimize the performance of my WebGIS application for displaying large, high-detail snow depth datasets in a small geographic extent ?
Additional Details:

The table structure includes a snow_depth field and a wkb_geometry field.
The data needs to be interactive, allowing users to query snow depth by moving their cursor over the map.
The application needs to support high-detail data visualization at both high and low zoom levels.

Any advice or suggestions?
Example of data visualization in Mapbox


Have you tried potree?

One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour]. We are not a discussion site,  so "advice" Questions will be closed as opinion-based. In theory, this could be asked in [Chat], but Chat is underutilized, so you may not get the participation needed.

The scope of an answer to this is that of a well paid, custom Terrain Tile Server implementation. That being said, you really want to investigate how to 1) encode snow depth into RGB with a formula supported by the framework of your choice (e.g. Mapbox GL understands two spedific RGB encodings), 2) create 1px-overlapping raster tile sets with that encoding 3) host it on a cloud storage of your choice (e.g. S3), 4) set this up as a terrain layer (e.g. map.setTerrain in Mapbox GL) and 5) access pixel values (depth) on mouseover (e.g. map.queryTerrainElevation(coordinate) in Mapbox GL).
